# Java Hashset returns false instead of true

Tags: java, string, arraylist, hashset

This block of code keeps returning false, and I can't figure out why.

```
List<String> angry = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((anger = angerSt.readLine()) != null) {
    angry.add(anger);
}
angerSt.close();
String[] angrywords = angry.toArray(new String[0]);
String word = "mad"
Set<String> angryWordSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(angrywords));
if(angryWordSet.contains(word)) 
{
    System.out.print("Yes");
    return true;
}
else return false;
```

The angryWordSet contains the strings mad, angry, livid and fuming. I printed it out to make sure it was there. I somehow keep getting false though. Can someone help with this?

Comment: Are you sure the line in is not `mad ` ie. with a space or special character? Can you print out the length of each String in the collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you have to check for the existence of leading and trailing whitespaces for each `angryWordSet` element.

```
for (String s : angryWordSet) {
    if (s.trim().equals(word)) return true;
}
return false;
```

---

About the wrong attempt to give an answer. I would leave a part of the previous answer in hoping that it will be helpful for someone.

> `Object[] toArray()` returns an array containing all of the elements
>   in this list in proper sequence (from first to last element). The
>   returned array will be "safe" in that no references to it are
>   maintained by this list. (In other words, this method must allocate a
>   new array). The caller is thus free to modify the returned array.
>
> `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)` returns an array containing all of the
>   elements in this list in proper sequence (from first to last element);
>   the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array.
>   If the list fits in the specified array, it is returned therein.
>   Otherwise, a new array is allocated with the runtime type of the
>   specified array and the size of this list.

Comment: Can you add an explanation as to how that will help?

Comment: According to its [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-), the List `toArray(T[] a)` method "Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper sequence (from first to last element); the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array. If the list fits in the specified array, it is returned therein. Otherwise, a new array is allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of this list.". This is different from your description of the method.

Comment: So what is the new explanation of why you prefer the no-arguments version?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, I was totally wrong, I corrected

Comment: This is a different answer from the one to which the comments apply. It would be clearer if you deleted this answer and added a new one.

Answer (score 4):

Following code works perfectly:

```
public static void main(String s[])
{
    List<String> angry = new ArrayList<String>();
    angry.add("a");
    angry.add("b");
    angry.add("c");
    angry.add("mad");
    angry.add("b");
    angry.add("b");
    String word = "mad";
    Set<String> angryWordSet = new HashSet<String>(angry);
    if (angryWordSet.contains(word))
    {
        System.out.print("Yes");

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("No");
    }
}
```

I am assuming when you do readline, words have '\n' or '\r' character added to it, thats why its not matching with the "word" varibale. Please verify, I didnt test it :)